# asterisk unable taking dtmf during mixmonitor

Tags: asterisk, record, dtmf

I am trying to take a dtmf by user when call starts recording(through mixmonitor) but asterisk is unable to identify that dtmf.
During the call between 2 user i want to take dtmf from one user but after the call starts recording asterisk is unable to detect dtmf

```
[from-pstn]
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,n,dial(DAHDI/09*********,s,1)

[dtmf]
exten => s,1,Mixmonitor(rrecord.wav)
exten => 7,1,playback(tone)
exten => 7,n,goto(othercontext)
```

This above code records the call but when i press 7 it donot play sound.Am i doing something wrong.How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

There are no any difference in call with mixmonitor or without.

Most likly you issue is codec change to compressed and dtmf=inband.

You code is compleatly wrong, i can't say what you triing to do. Dial command not accepting s,1 params. In dtmf context no waitexten or other command to collect dtmf.

I think you have read some book.

Comment: still not able to take dtmf

Comment: So what you expect me say you? if you have no dtmf, you have debug issue. Or create corect dialplan which will catch it.